# wordpress how to implement the php shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried to implement the code which can get the user region when the user open the page but it is not working i have used this code inside the functions.php

```
function user_region() { 
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
        return '<div class="user-region">'.$details->region.'</div>';  
    }  
    add_shortcode("get-user-region", "user_region");
```

this is my shortcode inside the functions.php and i have used the shortcode inside the wordpress page

```
<?php echo get-user-region_callback(); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[get-user-region]') ?>
```

I have tried both ways but both are not working no results are showing from this shortcode.

Comment: I do not understand the syntax that you are using for your first attempt. That's simply wrong. For the `echo do_shortcode()` you are not getting any output at all?

Comment: i am not getting any output  @yivi by trying both thats why i have used both code here

Comment: What have you tried to debug your problem? "Not working" is really broad

Comment: I am still working on this

Comment: You said you were not getting any output, but in a different comment you say "I'm still getting an empty div". It's one or the other. Are you getting an empty div, or are you getting no output?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your URL to `ipinfo` is incorrect.  If are treating the response as JSON, but the output of `https://ipinfo.io/ip is HTML.  You need to specify`/json` at the end:

```
https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json
```

Other than that, you need to check that `file_get_content` is enabled on your platform and that it allows remote url loading (setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)).

Comment: Still i am getting the empty div